# How to run Windows Steam games from Linux Steam (with WINE)?

Tags: wine, steam

I am currently using 2 versions of steam, the Linux one for games compatible with Linux, and the windows version in wine for games which are not compatible. I was wondering if it is possible to get wine to work on games in Linux steam (the one not using wine) , so I do not have to switch back and forth between the two steams.

Comment: This has been requested (2 months ago), whatever all what I've heard is that "Steam wants the games to run natively", but we don't think that some developers will port their games to Linux.

Comment: Does: > Games > "Add a Non-Steam Game to My Library" list the steam games installed with WINE? If so it may be possible to add them in the linux client like short-cuts.

Answer (score 6):

So, I know this is an old question, but there seems to be a way to do this. [Sort of](http://linuxgamecast.com/lgcbbs/index.php?p=/discussion/293/windows-downloads-in-linux-steam-resource-files-only/p2).

EDIT: So, having downloaded 1 game, it doesn't seem to be working. Launching the game does nothing. No errors.. just nada. So, YMMV.

It involves, tricking the client into thinking it can be installed by creating an appmanifest in the right folder. Luckily, since Steam is put together well and is tolerant of errors, you can just copy some other manifest, change a few fields, and it will automatically fix the file and start downloading the game.

For future reference in case the link breaks:

1. Right-click on your desired game in Steam. Click "Create Desktop Shortcut".
2. Open the shortcut up as text and locate the gameid. It will be on the Exec line. For example, "Exec=steam steam://rungameid/204880" means the gameid is 204880. (Bonus points for finding which game this is! :P)
3. Now we make a new manifest. (Oh, and if you have Steam open still, you can go ahead and close it.) Most likely, you'll go to ~/.local/share/Steam/SteamApps/. There will be several "appmanifest_xxxxxx.acf files (of variable length). These represent your installed games. Pick one (so far, it seems any one will work). Copy it and save it as appmanifest_gameid.acf (obviously replacing gameid with what it was). Now open it up and change the appID, GameID, name, and second name fields. Save it.
4. Re-open Steam.
5. ??? (Steam corrects our wrong file. Although, I've noticed some of the old properties remain which *may* come back to bite me/you/us.)
6. Profit! (it starts downloading)

And, as of writing, this is as far as I've gotten. My game is still downloading and I thought I'd share as I stumbled across this QA when I was looking for the same answer :)

Comment: Sins of a Solar Empire?

Comment: Probably? I certainly played that game a lot two years ago. :)

Answer (score 2):

Choose “Add a Game...” > “Add a Non-Steam Game”.

Search for the game in the provided list. If you find it, add it and you're done.

If you don't find it, [create a .desktop file](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles) where `Exec=wine /path/to/game/exe` and put it into `/usr/share/applications`.

Close and reopen the add game window. You should now find the game in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a very short script to launch the game (See: https://www.winehq.org/docs/wineusr-guide/running ) and then create an entry in your steam library using "Add a Non-Steam Game" that points to the script. This will mean that you will have the game in your list of games on the linux client.

However the windows Steam client will still have to load to run the game. I believe it's possible (maybe not at the time of the question original being asked though) for it to be loaded in some kind of minimal by default mode that will only show the system tray icon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your wine prefix with proton (GE for example). For that you need in proton folder (/home/nicourrrn/.steam/steam/compatibilitytools.d/GE-Proton7-43/files/share for 7.43 version) replace or remove default_pfx and take on that place symbol link on your wineprefix (ln -s ~./wine as default)

P.S. Sorry about my English.