# Can i download Windows version of games from Steam on Ubuntu for WINE?

Tags: windows, wine, games, steam, winetricks

When i search up a tutorial on how to open a game in WINE, i see "Install Wine blah blah blah... Once you are done, open the game and it should work".

How can i download the Windows version of games from Steam ignoring my platform?

I don't wanna download a pirated version of it.

Comment: Read this http://askubuntu.com/questions/257102/how-to-run-windows-steam-games-from-linux-steam-with-wine?rq=1

Comment: I don't think Valve lets you do that and this sounds like an [XY Problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/271411). The game data for Windows alone won't do you much good on Linux. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @DavidFoerster i wanna play on Wine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install Steam?](/q/1784). See the older answers that for Steam for Windows with Wine.

Comment: @DavidFoerster i meant that i wanna be able to download win version of games and open them with wine.

Comment: That's what the linked question is about. You'll find answers for both  Steam for Windows inside Wine and Steam for Linux.

Answer (score 5):

Uninstall Linux version of the game first.

In your Library *right click* on the game → *Properties* → check *Force the use of a specific Steam Play compatibility tool* → choose *newest Proton version*.

Perhaps you need to do this first for the checkbox to appear: *Steam* → *Settings* → *Steam Play* → check *Enable Steam Play for all other titles*.

Now you can install the Windows version.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use SteamCMD, you can specify that you want to download Linux/Mac/Windows version of any Steam ID that uses SteamPipe (which is just about all of them).

https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamCMD#Cross-Platform_Installation

Is a direct link to the specific bit you're after. An exert:

> **Cross-Platform Installation**
>
> It is possible to choose the platform for which SteamCMD should download files, even if it isn't the platform it is currently running on. This is done using the @sSteamCmdForcePlatformType variable. (Yes, those are two "s"es at the beginning of the variable name.) For example, to download the Windows CSGO dedicated server on Linux, you can run the following command:
>
> ...

Hope that helps!

**EDIT**: Just so you know, you'll need the Steam ID for a particular game to use this method, which you can find: https://steamdb.info/

Comment: Indeed, very useful for downloading on Linux and then copying to Windows. Many thanks, this helped a lot.